Cannot retrieve counts from finished job
Since a few days the usual code to get counts from a finised job e.g.:
service = QiskitRuntimeService(channel="ibm_quantum", token="mytoken")

job = service.job("myjobID")

results = job.result()

cnts=results[0].data.c.get_counts()

(c is the classical register)
Results in AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'data'.
Any ideas how to solve this issue?

What does your results[0] contain? What's its type?

Now I get the following:  {'type': 'SamplerPubResult', 'value': {'data': DataBin<>(c=BitArray(<shape=(), num_shots=1024, num_bits=1>)), 'metadata': {'circuit_metadata': {}}}}                                                                                                          the format is now different - older jobs looked like this:       PubResult(data=DataBin<>(c=BitArray(<shape=(), num_shots=1024, num_bits=1>)), metadata={'circuit_metadata': {}})

The way you can retrieve counts depends on the fact you used Qiskit primitives or AerSimulator from qiskit_aer:

In the former case, hence if you called SamplerV2 or EstimatorV2, you can retrieve counts with cnts=results[0].data.c.get_counts() paying attention to the exact name of the classical register;

In the latter case, you retrieve counts with cnts = results.get_counts().


Probably you are using AerSimulator.

I am using SamplerV2; but     cnts=results[0].data.c.get_counts().   works no longer for the recent job !

Can you post the full piece of code? I mean where you import the backend, execute the circuit and retrieve the result.

Try replacing cnts=results[0].data.c.get_counts() by cnts = results.get_counts(0)

Format of data container has changed. Simply replace:
cnts=results[0].data.c.get_counts() by
cnts=results[0]['_ _value__']['data'].c.get_counts().
